# How to use chrome extension api with gwt in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, google-chrome-extension

I'm using GWT in Eclipse to build what will be a Packaged App for Chrome. I need to access chrome api's but I'm not sure how to add support so that it compiles. Any guidance? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use [JSNI](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html), and possibly [JavaScript Overlay Types](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html) (unless someone has created a wrapper library already that you can reuse).